# How can I perform a word count in spring-batch and sort the output?

Tags: spring-batch

Given an input of some objects each containing a set of strings, I want to count the number of occurrences of each string for the entire batch, and output the word counts (to a CSV in my case) alongside each string (preferably sorted by frequency). How can I achieve this in spring batch? I can't find any suitable examples. I've tried to implement this using item readers/processors but am getting the output duplicated, I'm assuming because it's chunked? Should I use Tasklets for this?

[Spring Batch : Aggregating records and write count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825535/spring-batch-aggregating-records-and-write-count) seems close to what I want to achieve, but it's not clear to me how this is working.

The input is along the lines of:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": ["foo", "bar"]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "tags": ["foo", "baz"]
}
...]
```

and the desired output from that would be

```
foo, 2
bar, 1
baz, 1
```

Comment: Could you give an example of input and output? If need, I will build a small example for you

Comment: `I've tried to implement this using item readers/processors but am getting the output duplicated` Can you share this code? I will try to help you make it work as needed.